# Like query with "." symbol in string Query in spring JpaRepository

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, cql, spring-data-cassandra

I would like to write a like query in JpaRepository but it is not obeying the like query :

LIKE "abc" and "abc.com" are two string and when we do like :

```
@Query("Select * from table_name where column_name  like ?0'%' ALLOW FILTERING ")
List<entity> findPlaceContainingKeywordAnywhere(String keyword)
```

it is returning both the values when we pass :

```
repository.findPlaceContainingKeywordAnywhere("abc.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will search only string starting with "abc." also I think there is some issue with query

Try this

```
@Query("Select * from table_name where column_name  like %:keyword% ALLOW FILTERING ")
List<entity> findPlaceContainingKeywordAnywhere(@Param("keyword") String keyword)
```